# Distribution of divisions of a circle

Tags: distribution-of-primes

When viewing distributions divisions of a circle, an interesting behavior is displayed.

Take n nested/circumscribed circles. Divide each circle in to n parts and plot a point for each division.

There are patterns formed. The integers seem to form parabola like structures. Dividing the circle in to prime divisions have a sort of of chaotic structure but some type of pattern seems to exist.

I'm just curious if anyone has investigated this behavior. I realize that it is just "dots" and there are many patterns, but the integer one clearly has some sort of "parabolic" like characteristics while the primes seem to have many sub patterns that relate(sort of fractal like).

[image]